# É possível criar uma chave estrangeira a partir de outro database?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql

Eu quero fazer referência de uma chave estrangeira a partir de um banco diferente, vi em alguns fóruns que só é necessário fazer `` `nome_database`.`nome_tabela` ``, mas não está funcionando.
O meu código é o seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE `relatorio_gestao`.`usuario_setores` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `id_unidade_ifpe`
FOREIGN KEY (`id_unidade_ifpe`)
REFERENCES `bancobase`.`unidade_ifpe` (`id_unidade_IFPE`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não há erros na construção da `FOREIGN KEY`. Uma database é `relatorio_gestao` e a outra é `bancobase`? O nome do campo na tabela `unidade_ifpe` é `id_unidade_IFPE` (maiúsculo)?

Comment: Criei as databases e tabelas em minha máquina e funcionou perfeitamente. O seu código está correto. As duas tabelas são INNODB? As colunas são do mesmo tipo e possuem o mesmo tamanho? Quando responder, coloca comentário e no início coloca arroba e nome_do_usuario (Lucas Henrique) para me notificar.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Na documentação básica do Mysql não prevê esta síntaxe database.table, sei que por exemplo o Mysql aceita *check constraints* mas estas não tem efeito , talvez seja o mesmo caso.

Em Oracle implementei algo assim por meio de *triggers*, fazendo todas as checagens de integridade por meio de *selects*, trabalhoso mas funcionou.